# Paper or Ink that naturally degrades in a month or less?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, written-material

The end result is that a delivered envelope or the writing on it is designed to completely decay within 2 weeks to a month, ideally through natural processes caused by the type of materials used, so that the paper itself has decayed or the writing is completely illegible.  It does not strictly have to be 'paper' and can be something more easily degradable, but that can still support writing before it does.

This should be achieved without any other timed mechanism that may introduce some other substance to the envelope after a set period of time.

Edit: This is not for passing secret spy messages, but because in world the written word is more mentally harmful to view the more times it has been seen. This is a safety precaution to avoid leaving loose notes behind. Nobody would be looking to uncover hidden words with a high level of scrutiny (hence the longer than immediate timeframe for decomposition)

What are some best methods to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I know of no kind of paper which self-destructs in a month (without burning). But there are many inks which self-erase in a short period of time. For use in an ink-jet printer, use something like [Paper Saver](https://www.aiche.org/sites/default/files/cep/20201013_2.pdf) ink from Blue Planet Ink. For hand-written messages, use a common [self-erasing pen](https://www.google.com/search?q=self-erasing+pen), of the kind popular with tailors etc. who want to make temporary marks on fabrics.

Comment: Can you coat the paper after you write? (Eg dip in a fluid) You'll have *x* days to read it afterwards.

Comment: Imagine the ten commandments are inscribed in ice! Actually ice Scrabble if you will ;D

Comment: Newspaper crumbles over a few decades because of residual acid from manufacturing in the paper. Anybody know how much faster it might crumble if more acid were deliberately added during manufacture, or maybe sprayed on after writing on it?

Comment: @nigel222 a relevant comparison might be the use of lemon juice as invisible ink.  That can certainly survive days to weeks (and eventually becomes visible without the normal  heating).  It does eventually become brittle, but I'm not sure how long that takes - probably too long

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### That's not ink, it's mold.

Letters are printed using water mixed with dormant, black-colored, water-activated mold as ink. After 7 days, the mold has started growing and has become hard to read. After 14 days, the mold has grown significantly and destroyed its readability. In 30 days, you have a (albeit disgusting) sheet of mold.

Comment: The only problem is that the rate of mold growth depends heavily on conditions, so a dry message might be readable indefinitely.

Comment: This is very true — inversely a humid environment would make it unreadable very quickly.

Answer (score 8):

## Use the 'ink' from receipts

Many (most? All?) Receipts use thermal paper, which is used to 'write' the receipt.

Sometimes I need to hold in to a receipt for guarantee or something similar. Some however fade much more quickly. Thanks to even the smallest bit of light and/or friction, possibly even by doing nothing the letters start to disappear. Not sure if this is intentional, like biodegradable or to prevent returns of a product, but it shows that 'ink' that disappears after a time is very possible. Maybe the kind of paper also helps, reverting to it's original state after a time. You can also turn it around and have the paper turn black slowly as the normal temperature is already too high, starting the reaction.

Comment: [Thermal paper](ikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_paper) is notorius for this self-erasing effect.

Comment: I depends on the temperature, though. I still find readable receipts in the pockets of my cloths from the last cold season - got them hanging in a wardrobe in a room with A/C.

Comment: Receipt printers don't usually use ink. They use thermal paper instead, paper with a coating that turns black when heated.

Comment: Updated the answer because of suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

## Be Careful, someone has thought how to get around that already...

Depending on your needs, [THIS](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121414/self-destructing-messages/121434) question may answer your question.

If you've ever been to the [International spy Museum](https://www.spymuseum.org/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIk6GilYzn9AIViZ7tCh0xQgfCEAAYAiAAEgKmFPD_BwE), you'll know that people have tried a LOT of different ways to make messages that either can't be read by anyone who you don't want to, or that are destroyed as soon as they are read.

Codes can be broken. Even the pressure on paper leaves an imprint that can be read. Ink you can't see leaves a residue that's detectable to sophisticated enough sensors. So what's a secretive person supposed to do?

Your question implies the message must no longer be readable after two weeks, but says nothing about codes.

- The simplest way to achieve your goal is to use paper that is readily [water-soluble](https://www.winklersmagicwarehouse.com/product/dissolvo-spy-paper/), edible or alcohol-soluble and preferably non-toxic. That way, the reader can eat or drink the message when done and the message is gone. Swallow it, or at least pop it in your mouth, drop it in a drink, etc.. and it's gone.
- Another alternative is paper with messages only read by ultraviolet light that are then [destroyed by the heat of a hairdryer](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2217550-coated-paper-holds-secret-messages-that-can-be-erased-with-a-hairdryer/).
- [Flash paper](https://www.vanishingincmagic.com/flash-paper/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-flash-paper-and-flash-cotton/) is hyper-combustible and leaves no residue.
- [Potassium permanganate](https://melscience.com/US-en/chemistry/experiments/chemical-ink-eraser/) decolorizes ink, although there will likely be a residue of detectible chemicals for a sophisticated spy to detect. Perhaps it or micro-beads of it embedded in the paper that release as they absorb moisture would do the job. But the ink would need to dry without releasing the permanganate, so a water-free solvent would be needed and a dye known to degrade in the presence of potassium permanganate. The paper would need to be kept in a desiccated condition (like a sealed water-proof envelope with a desiccant pack in it).
- Digitally, there are apps that allow you to create [self-destructing messages](https://metro.co.uk/2020/11/03/how-to-turn-on-whatsapp-self-destruct-messages-and-protect-your-chats-13528390/) good for only a set amount of time.
- A special printer has been designed that causes paper to [burst into flame](https://www.therecycler.com/posts/printer-creates-self-destructing-paper/) after about 60 seconds. If such a letter were printed in an atmosphere that had no oxygen, and sealed inside a container with inert gas, it would burst into flame shortly after opening.
- Some pigments and preparations, like film, are destroyed when exposed to light. Read in proper "darkroom" conditions, the messages are readable, but rapidly over-expose once exposed to normal light.
- Encoded test results: The information is encoded  in the form of unstable organic molecules of the kind commonly tested by hospital or clinical labs. These can be read, and each numeric value corresponds to a letter in a cypher. These tests often are unstable and become increasingly degraded over time, when left at room temperature, or exposed to light (like many vitamins). Identify a test that needs to be performed within a set amount of time, kept at stable temperatures, and can't be exposed to light. The tubes are placed in order in a rack. So if they are left out, exposed to warmth and light, get too old, or are even dumped out so the tubes are no longer in order, then the message is lost. Run the tests, and you get a series of numbers that correspond to the letters of the message. It certainly doesn't LOOK like a message, either!

Comment: That digital one shouldn't count. It's more like an instruction to throw the message into the fireplace after reading; it's certainly not automatic. (Data can't automatically destroy itself.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 They all have something imperfect about them, and I'm not sure there IS a perfect, so I'm throwing out alternatives. DNA is  data, but it needs an infrastructure to self-destruct, so it depends on the data being in the right setting.

Answer (score 2):

#### Non-secrecy

For a message that needs to disappear for public-safety reasons (transcript of unholy knowledge?), but that doesn't have to remain secret against determined attack:

**Edibility**

I suggest you use an agar plate or icing/frosting, depending on whether your local ants prefer to eat protien or sugar. The wildlife will take care of a discarded message for you, because it tastes good. Sugar-based writing can also be susceptible to humidity.

**Viscosity**

In a hot climate, scraping your message into a bar of pitch will work, since it will gradually flow into the grooves. You can vary the substance based on your needs, pitch may not be fast enough in a colder climate.

Answer (score 1):

The principle - make the ink contain a catalyst the triggers the decomposition of the paper. The thickness of the paper and/or concentration of the "destructive agent" that the ink catalyses can be used to tune the lifetime of the note.
For example (I would need to try it to see if it is practical): [sodium percarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_percarbonate) in the structure of the paper in interaction with an iron oxide based ink should trigger a slowly advancing oxidation reaction (also bound to the amount of water the percabornate can get to absorb from atmosphere).

Which brings another idea: highly hygroscopic paper which gets into a mush state outside of a sealed envelope that keeps it dry en route to delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is probably easier than you might think.  One of the hard parts of making ink is to make it **not** fade.  So instead of trying to make ink last, you work to make it not last.

Any basic alchemist should be able to whip something up in a few months, and if this is a normal need in your world, any alchemist would already know several recipes (as in could make it today).

Note that chemical analysis would probably still find the "ink".